# Rails override passed request params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 7 API only app I'm receiving the request with these params:

```
  def event_params
    params.permit(:event, :envelopeId, :action, :recipient)
  end
```

Inside the controller I need to set a guard based on `event_params[:action]` like below:

```
    class EventsController < BaseController
      def event_callback
        return unless event_params[:action] == 'envelopefinished'
        (...)
      end
    end
```

But it turns out the `:action` is default ActionController::Parameters parameter that represents the name of the action being performed (i.e., the method being called). Is it possible to get parameter event_params[:action] which was passed inside the JSON file without changing the JSON key name to something else?

Comment: Those are some weird param names by Rails standards. The convention is like `envelope_id`.

Comment: @tadman I know that but I cannot change that since the params comes from the external API without my control of it.

Comment: I feel for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its actually the router that overwrites `params[:action]` and `params[:controller]` but you can still access the raw parameters through the request object:

```ruby
request.POST["action"]
```

This odd looking method (yeah its a method not a constant) is from [Rack::Request::Helpers](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request/Helpers#POST-instance_method) and gives the parsed parameters from the request body.

Comment: I guess if you really wanted to you could write a piece of middleware that you inject before the router that copies `params[:action]` to some other key like `:_action`. https://ieftimov.com/posts/writing-rails-middleware/